# Which event type is triggered when a slack app is installed onto a workspace for the first time?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to build an app that does something when it is first installed onto a workspace, eg: Ping every team member.

I couldn't find an event type that gets triggered upon app install:
https://api.slack.com/events

Is there a way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be a misunderstanding of the events concepts here. Events are always directly linked to one specific Slack app and needs to be processed by that very app. There is no such thing as "general" events for things happening on a workplace, like a new app being installed. Ergo there is no event for app installation.

Nevertheless you can implement the functionality you mentioned with Slack, e.g. pinging all team members once an app is first installed. All you need to do is include this function in the [installation process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) of your Slack app and e.g. start pinging after the installation process is complete and the app verified that it was the first installation to this workspace. You do not need an event for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer because I was wondering the same thing and wanted to share what I found. On this [oauth tutorial](https://github.com/slackapi/oauth-tutorial/blob/master/oauth.md), it has the following code snippet:

```
app.get('/auth', function(req, res){
  if (!req.query.code) { // access denied
    return;
  }
  var data = {form: {
    client_id: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    code: req.query.code
  }};
  request.post('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access', data, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Get an auth token
      let oauthToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
      // OAuth done- redirect the user to wherever
      res.redirect(__dirname + "/public/success.html");
    }
  })
});
```

I believe instead of the line `res.redirect(__dirname + "/public/success.html");` at that point you can make a request to ping everyone or even call a function to do so directly there, and it will trigger immediately once the app has been installed.