# where is the "installed_app" event in Slack App

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm confused in Slack App's developing.

I want to send the some messages to user when they installed my application.

But there is no appropriate event in the exists like installed_app event.
( uninstalled_app event only exists)

[image: screenshot]

which event should I specify to receive the event that user installed my application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event trigger for app installation (`app uninstalled` events is however present in the Events API, find more about that [here](https://api.slack.com/events/app_uninstalled)) , this is because events are tied to each specific app and the processing needs to be conducted by that very app. You can, however, implement certain functionalities like sending messages to users after an app is installed in your workspace. You can find more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997900/which-event-type-is-triggered-when-a-slack-app-is-installed-onto-a-workspace-for)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link.
kaimcg's answer looks good for me.

My environment will receive the message from slack when user finished the OAuth process. I can treat it as the install event message.
  
Then  I get the users information in the workspace and send them the message.

Comment: How does this work when an enterprise user installs your org-wide app to their org? When the OAuth processes finishes, your app hasn't been added to any workspaces yet (see also https://api.slack.com/enterprise/apps/changes-install#redirects). How to detect if the app was added to a workspace in that case?